# fatal: function name previously defined

Tags: gawk

For the listing below, I get an error:

> fatal: function name `myprint' previously defined

```
$3 > 0     { myprint ($3) }

function myprint(num)
{
    printf "%6.3g\n", num
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that I had an extra space after the call and between the parameters:

```
myprint ($3)
```

should be:

```
myprint($3)
```

Comment: This error message also shows up when you define a function twice with the same signature.